# Using using dynamically

Tags: julia

I want to use modules dynamically and I know their name, but creating a module and then applying using like this:

```
using PyPlot
a = Module(:Plots)
using a
```

will yield an excpetion telling me that a is not definied. Which is a very unintuitive error message, since when you do this on the repl you can use 'a' afterwards. Just in combination with using it tells you that it is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is emitted by `Base.require`, so you should use `using Main.a` or `using .a` instead:

> require(module::Symbol)
>
> This function is part of the implementation of using / import, if a module is not already
>     **defined in Main**. It can also be called directly to force reloading a module, regardless of
>     whether it has been loaded before (for example, when interactively developing libraries).
>   ...
>   When searching for files, require first looks for package code under **Pkg.dir()**, then tries paths
>     in the global array **LOAD_PATH**. require is case-sensitive on all platforms, including those with
>     case-insensitive filesystems like macOS and Windows.

Or just use `module` keyword to define a module on the fly:

```
module A
...
end

using A
```

For an existing module, you could also dynamically use it via `eval(using module-name)`.

Comment: Thank you. The eval does exactly what I want.

Comment: Beware of `eval` here. Only use it like this in the REPL, or in a non-precompiled package. Precompilation is not designed for this kind of dynamic usage. So if you're doing this as a way to skip having to have a package as a dependency... don't. (Besides, if it's to skip a Plots.jl dependency, no package should use Plots.jl directly and should instead depend on RecipesBase.jl).

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas well how else am I going to do it if I do not know what the dependencies are yet ( at compile time )?

Comment: Then don't precompile, or design differently. What package are you having this issue with? It shouldn't be plots because no package should be directly depending on it.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I don't know which package the user will throw at me, thats the point. To give some information. I am accepting some user-input, where the user will write using <hisCoolPackage> and then I will have to(!) seralize his data to be used on a different machine later. Now to deseralize I need to know which package to be 'using' and I know the package, I just need to emulate his 'using' in the script on the other machine.

Comment: I see, so then you're stuck with this. That's a very dynamic workflow, so this will likely won't always work if you don't precompile your package. It might work often enough that you can get away with it, but if you have issues disabling precompilation is likely the first thing to try. Good luck.